# Redirect to an alternate domain but keep sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect

So I've acquired a new domain that intend on using to replace my old domain. I intend on moving all the content from the old domain to the new one. I'm looking to redirect people from `old.com` to `new.com`, but keep the subdirectories. 
For example, when users follow the following URL

`old.com/directory1/directory2`
they are redirected to 
`new.com/directory1/directory2`

I'm assuming htaccess would be the best option in this case. If it is, I'd appreciate some pointers as to how to set this up. Otherwise, if you know of any other methods that would be more appropriate, let me know.
 Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily with a simple 301 redirect.

This should work for what you are wanting to do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```